Trying to remember an old cartoon movie from my childhood (was very trippy)
As the title says, I'm trying to remember a movie I saw when I was very young (im 29 now, so could have been the late 80s).
What I do remember is that the cartoon focused around a young boy who becomes a slave for a witch (no idea why) who also turns him into some kind of hideous freak, to the point where when he manages to escape, even his own family refuse to accept who he is.
The main thing I remember about this movie is that it had a very very trippy animation style (think badly done stop motion, but with a kind of picture continuation from one image to the next), so why it wasn't blurry it was very 'wavy' and strange.
I think the boy might have had some kind of friend in the form of a rodent or something while he was captured and a goose may or may not have featured.

I'm pretty sure you're describing the plot of the German folktale Der Zwerg Nase (Nose the Dwarf), where a boy has to serve a witch for seven years and when he goes back to his family, they can't recognize him because he has a hump and a huge nose. He later runs into a princess that the witch turned into a goose.
As for the version you're after, that's a bit harder. There's one from the early 80s and one from 1986, but they look like regular stop-motion or puppet productions and don't seem particularly trippy to me. There were also a couple of animated and live action adaptations, but they don't seem to fit either.
Anyway, here's the one from 1986 (stop-motion):



And here's the one from the early 80s (puppets):




You sir are a legend.

@Mark No problem. :) If this is correct, don't forget to click on the check mark to resolve the question.

That is without a doubt the story I remember. Though I have to be honest, this raises more questions than it answers. I have no memory of the story being in German (nor do I know how I would have been able to access a German show in the first place). I'm honestly not sure if there even was dialog. I should make my original question clearer, the show I saw was animated, just really strangely (basically imagine this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lv8IezFbADc with chronic ghosting). You have given me a vital first step and for that I am grateful.

Sorry, and I hope you find it (you can put it up when you do).
